# mysql update ~ 25 times slower than select. Is is normal?

Tags: mysql

Update code

```
$stmt_update = $db->prepare( ' 
UPDATE table SET Column = 1 
WHERE Id = 17
' ); 
$stmt_update->execute( );
```

Takes ~ 25 miliseconds

But

```
$stmt_select = $db->prepare( ' 
SELECT 
`Text`, 
`NameOfPerson`, 
`EmailOne`, 
`Phone`, 
`EmailTwo` 
FROM table_name
WHERE Id = ?
' ); 
$stmt_select->execute( array( trim( $_GET["two"] ) ) );
```

This takes ~ one millisecond.

Is it normal (such difference)? Any ideas how to make faster update (to execute faster)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes sense.  But, you need to learn a few things about measuring performance.  The first query may be reading data into memory.  This takes a bit of time.  When you run the second query it is already there.  Often, the second time you run exactly the same query is faster than the first time -- unless you fiddle with caching options on the server.

The `update` is going to be slower because databases have what are called ACID properties.  That means that the update is not completed until the database is as sure as it can be that the change has been made.  Typically, this means committing a log transaction to disk, so you are waiting for the disk write to be completed.  It is not enough for the disk write to start -- it has to be completed.  It also means that the `update` has acquire locks for the parts of the table being updated.

In addition, the database eventually has to write the actual modified data pages to disk.  In MySQL, this probably depends on the storage engine.  So, you might be waiting for that.

A `select` doesn't modify anything.  It just reads.  So there is some time for getting the data, but as soon as it is in memory, the query can process and finish.

In addition, `update`s may generate other work for the database engine -- such as updating indexes and running triggers.  It is unclear if these are defined on your table.

So, I would expect an `update` to take longer than a `select`.

Comment: I changed order (first select, then update). The same result. Select much faster than update.

Comment: No option to make update faster? Table type is `InnoDB`. One column is primary and auto increment.

Comment: @user2118559 
You could use faster hardware (e.g. SSD drive) or faster software (e.g. non-ACID DB, fastest would be a RAM-only database).

Comment: Storing the logs on SSD speeds up updates/inserts/deletes most databases, but I'm not sure about MySQL.  Do note that 25 ms for an update does *not* mean that the database is limited to 40 updates per second.  In a multi-threaded environment, databases can be doing multiple things at the same time (locking permitted).